# give label text to y -axis in am charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using Amcharts for generating charts. 
 I want to give label to Y axis such as units. (eg:temp, Marks, etc)
 I also want to include an image with the label text.Searched through all docs       but none of them can help me.

Comment: Do you have any code? This is a broad question to answer without a specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SImply set valueAxis.title = "your title";
Or, if its' JSON:

{
   title:"your title"
}

Or use [live editor](http://live.amcharts.com) and add it in the value axis control.